# How to write a function returns either Integer or Bool based on a user defined data type?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, polymorphism

I am given a data type like the following

```
data Value = IntVal Integer |
             BoolVal Bool
             deriving Show
```

I am trying to write a function `getVal` that takes a Value and returns the actual value inside. I was trying to achieve with pattern matching

```
getVal (IntVal val) = val
getVal (Bool bool) = bool
```

But Haskell complains about the returning types
    Couldn't match expected type 'Integer' with actuall type 'Bool'

So I gave it a signature returns a type variable

```
getVar :: Value -> a
```

But it won't work either

Comment: How were you expecting to use that function `getVar`?

Comment: @Bergi The actual logic of this function is more complex than this, I am just trying to at lease get the input and output format right before proceeding

Comment: @Bergi it does actually make sense if you take into account type inference. see the examples down my answer

Comment: No, I don't mean the logic of the function itself, that's irrelevant. But how do you think would you call `getVar`?

Comment: @behzad.nouri: Yeah, but you've changed the result type to a `Maybe`, so that it can fail when the input is unexpected.

Comment: @Bergi that is not the point

Comment: @behzad.nouri: It was *my* point :-) One just cannot do `if getVar (IntVal 5) then …` or `getVar (BoolVal False) + 5`, so I was asking the OP for his use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*One* way to do it is to use type-classes, to make a function *polymorphic in return value*:

```
\> :t getVal
getVal :: GetValue a => Value -> Maybe a
```

by a simple code as in bellow:

```
data Value = IntVal Integer
           | BoolVal Bool
             deriving Show

class GetValue a where
    getVal :: Value -> Maybe a

instance GetValue Integer where
    getVal (IntVal i) = Just i
    getVal          _ = Nothing

instance GetValue Bool where
    getVal (BoolVal b) = Just b
    getVal           _ = Nothing
```

and let the type-inference decide the right function:

```
\> import Data.Maybe (fromJust)
\> (3 +) .fromJust . getVal $ IntVal 5  -- getVal :: Value -> Maybe Integer
8
\> not . fromJust . getVal $ BoolVal False  -- getVal :: Value -> Maybe Bool
True
```

Answer (score 10):

Yes, this can be handled with help of type classes or GADTs or you can even use `cast` leveraging `Data.Typeable`. But all those thing are useful when you know Haskell well, and when you know what you're doing exactly.

In your case, you should really try to understand how Haskell works in general. Haskell is about imposing wise invariants that make it impossible to write “bad” programs (well, that's how I put it). This is done via type system, and without those invariants attached you cannot really do anything.

So now, you cannot do much with a thing of type `a`, because you don't know much about it. If you want to return value from function that can be either `Int` or `Bool` (that's actually possible see existential quantification), you will be able to perform actions on that value that can be performed on `Int` *and* on `Bool`. You can get textual representation of that value for example.

Chances are you want more than that. In this case you probably shouldn't try to return `Int` *and* `Bool` at the same time without a way to understand what exactly you have as a result.

So, you can do the following for example:

```
getVar :: Value -> Either Int Bool
```

Or you can just dispatch:

```
case Value of
  IntVal  x -> doWhatYouWantToDoWithInteger x
  BoolVal x -> doWhatYouWantToDoWithBoolean x
```

This is natural flow of Haskell. In every branch of program you now know what you're dealing with.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

That's a job for `GADT`s:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Value a where
    IntVal  :: Integer -> Value Integer
    BoolVal :: Bool    -> Value Bool

getVal :: Value a -> a
getVal (IntVal  i) = i
getVal (BoolVal b) = b
```

Answer (score 2):

user3237465 and behzad.nouri have provided answers to your specific question. However I wonder if you are thinking by analogy with OO and dynamically typed languages. If you are taking "Value" as an argument to a function then you should use pattern matching to do the Right Thing with the value it holds.  So suppose you are writing a function "showValue" to return the value as a string. I guess you are trying to do something like:

```
showValue :: Value -> String
showValue v = let v1 = getValue v in <something>
```

But that won't work in Haskell because the type system insists on knowing what type "v1" is. Instead you write it like this:

```
showValue (IntVal i) = "The Value is an integer " ++ show i
showValue (BoolVal b) = "The Value is a boolean " ++ show b
```